# Connect .content:hover and img:hover, so they activate at the same time

Tags: css, hover

I am trying to connect these 2 hover classes, so they activate at the same time:

```
#recent-posts .content:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
}

#recent-posts img:hover {
    outline: 11px solid #ff7454;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

So whenever you hover over content OR an image both hover classes will activate. I have tried a bunch of different ways to do this and read all over but this seems a little more complicated than it should be.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is a jsfiddle with what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/zpwnL/

Comment: can you post a DEMO please.

Comment: it depends much on your HTML structure and the capability to edit your HTML so that we can have an easy solution.

Comment: @KheemaPandey I have updated question with a fiddle to demonstrate. I am also using bootstrap 3, but this is just css figured it was not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the parent selector to style the child-elements:

```
#recent-posts .thumbnail:hover {
...
}

#recent-posts .thumbnail:hover img {
 box-shadow:....
}
```

If the elements would not have one common parent, you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Box shadow doesn't work at all when I try this way, actually this was same answer as above. This causes the shadow to go under the img instead of .thumbnail class.

Comment: It is working: http://jsfiddle.net/zpwnL/4/ And here with a blue shadow to be more noticeable: http://jsfiddle.net/zpwnL/7/

Comment: Ohhhhh okay, sorry I had the classes mixed up! Awesome, totally makes sense now thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the `:hover` for an element from this element to keep adding selectors also apply to these

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LD4qN/

update with you fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zpwnL/

Comment: Ah I think you did not update fiddle on your end, it is the same link I posted. I am trying to figure it out with yours but a little confusing.

Comment: Box shadow comes up under the image now instead of .thumbnail class, I need it under the thumbnail.